# problema al agregar usuario en crud

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariadb

Amigos en la imagen me aparece ese error al querer agregar un usuario a un crud ya revise mi redacción y no me deja. mi codigo es el siguiente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]`<?php include_once("conexion.php");

```
$nombre     = $_POST['txtnombre'];
$correo     = $_POST['txtcorreo'];
$telefono   = $_POST['txttelefono'];
$edad   = $_POST['txtedad'];
$curp   = $_POST['txtcurp'];
$sexo   = $_POST['txtsexo'];
$rfc    = $_POST['txtrfc'];
$nss    = $_POST['txtnss'];
$fecha  = $_POST['txtfecha'];
$especialidad   = $_POST['txtesp'];
$cedula = $_POST['txtcedula'];

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO usuarios(nom,correo,tel,edad,curp,sexo,rfc,nss,fecha_n,especialidad,cedula) 
VALUES('$nombre','$correo', '$telefono','$edad','$curp','$sexo,'$rfc','$nss','$fecha','$especialidad','$cedula')");
```

header("Location:index.php");

?>
`

Comment: El error se presenta cuando hay un error de sintaxis o escritura, en tu caso faltaría una comilla en la variable `'$sexo'`...

Answer (score 2):

Hay un fallo tipográfico: te falta una comilla en `'$sexo`, que debería ser `'$sexo'`.